# Get document id From Firestore Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the document id from `Firestore` by executing a query like this:-

```
func updateStatusInFirestore() {

let orderid = saleOrder.first?.Orderid ?? ""
print(orderid)
let settings = db.settings
settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
db.settings = settings
 self.db.collection("SaleOrders").whereField("orderid", isEqualTo: "\(orderid)").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            self.documentid = document.documentID
            print(self.documentid)
        }
    }
}

}
```

In which I am getting the order id from my model class and it is printing the value of order id but when I am trying to put it in `whereField` query it is not exectuing the query and I am not getting any result in my console.

If I use like this it is working

```
self.db.collection("SaleOrders").whereField("orderid", isEqualTo: "ji20190205091948").getDocuments
```

but when I use like this

```
let orderid = saleOrder.first?.Orderid ?? ""
self.db.collection("SaleOrders").whereField("orderid", isEqualTo: "\(orderid)").getDocuments
```

It is not working. What is wrong I am doing. Please help?

Comment: orderId is already a `String` don't write `"\(orderid)"` just do `self.db.collection("SaleOrders").whereField("orderid", isEqualTo: orderid).getDocuments`

Comment: I tried it but it is not working

Comment: Oh ok, it's an optional. So unwrap it like `guard let orderid = saleOrder.first?.Orderid else { return }` and then do `self.db.collection("SaleOrders").whereField("orderid", isEqualTo: orderid).getDocuments`

Comment: Still same not working :(

Comment: is it printing the same value after unwrapping it? I don't see any other cause for the problem\

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla....thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Solved the problem. We just need to add one `if` condition to get the documentId of that particular collection from `Firestore`

```
for document in snapshot!.documents {

  if document == document {
   print(document.documentID)
     }
       }
```